# How can I check my glue record ip update was successful?

Tags: dns, nameservers

I changed the ip address of the glue records at my domain registrar (Moniker). But still the name servers  are pointing to the old server. How can I verify that the updation was successful?

I tried `dig NS mydomain.com @a.gtld-servers.net.` and it returned the old IP address. All the root name servers are returning the old ip address.

Comment: It's not *root* nameservers, it's a TLD nameservers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your check is ok. Moniker did not submit your new record to the TLD. Check with moniker, since .com TLD should update glue records in 5 minutes at most.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sandman4. Everyone other than you told me it will take 24-48 hours for the change to propagate to all gtld-servers. I talked to Moniker support and you were right. As per their advice, I edited and re-saved the records, and the ip address got updated instantly at all the gtld-servers.